# How to remove shadow between tabs and action bar?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, manifest

How can I remove shadow between tabs and action bar?

This is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.tosi.lap">
       <application
                android:allowBackup="true"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:supportsRtl="true"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
                <activity
                    android:name=".MainActivity"
                    android:label="@string/app_name"
                    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </activity>
                <activity
                    android:name=".FilmsSerial"
                    android:label="@string/title_activity_films_serial"
                    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
                </activity>
            </application>

        </manifest>
```

This is my app_bar_main.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.tosi.lap.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            android:elevation="0dp" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

When I added `app:elevation="0dp"` it don't show items in action bar.
How can I solve this problem?
Thank you for answer.

Comment: Shadow does not relate to `manifest`. Put your `xml`

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0); works for lollipop + devices. fir erlier ones  you can put <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>

Comment: also if you have a tab layout and you just want to remove the shadow in the middle put both with the same elevation!

Comment: @PedroTeran thank you for reply but it does not work